# Ren'py при скачивании SDK выдает ошибку

Tags: sdk, renpy

делал порт на андройд для новеллы, Скачал JDK, потом нужно было скачать SDK, но после попытки выдает это:

```
While running game code:
```

`File "game/android.rpy", line 503, in <module> File "game/mobilebuild.rpy", line 214, in call File "game/mobilebuild.rpy", line 238, in check_process CalledProcessError: Command '['java.exe', '-classpath', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\renpy-8.1.1-sdk\\rapt\\buildlib', 'CheckJDK8']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Удалял все JDK, даже Node.js на случай, переустанавливал Renpy, но все равно выдает ошибку